# What is the correct way to include jquery libraries including CSS when using create-react-app?

Tags: jquery, css, npm, webpack, create-react-app

I'm trying to utilize a jquery library called select2 in my React app created by create-react-app.

I have added jquery and select2 to my package.json and I can make the javascript work.

However, the styling does not work as the css file of select 2 is not included correctly.

I can see the following file inside my project:

```
node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css
```

and of course I can copy the file into public/css and add this to my index.html:

```
<link href="css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I'm sure there is a better way utilizing the power of webpack and the create-react-app toolchain. But how?

Comment: http://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

I often just require the css in the index of my app.

index.js:
`require('node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css')`

Comment: Great, I didn't know you could include css-files using require. Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way is to "import" the CSS into the .js file that references your jquery library:

```
import 'select2/dist/css/select2.min.css';
```

That way, the CSS will be included in the bundle.js file that is generated, and you have "localized" this dependency to the code that requires it.

On a related note: you may wish to Google "react select" and explore the many libraries that provide a more "React-ish" way of implementing a widget.